# A special case of group extensions, other then the semidrect product.

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology, group-extensions

It's a well-known fact that if $A$ an Abelian group and $G$ is a group, then all group extension of $G$ by $A$ is isomorphic with the group ($A\times G,\,\bullet)$, where the group operation $\bullet$ is

$$(a_1,g_1)\bullet(a_2,g_2) = (a_1+\varphi_{g_1}(a_2)+f(g_1,g_2),\,g_1g_2)\tag{1}$$

where

1. $\varphi:(A\times G)\to A: (a,g)\mapsto \varphi_g(a)$ is a group action of $G$ on $A$
2. $f: G\times G\to A$ is a cocycle, i.e. satisfies $f(g_1,\,g_2g_3)+\varphi_{g_1}(f(g_2,\,g_3)) = f(g_1g_2,\,g_3)+f(g_1,\,g_2)$.

These are some special cases of this:

1. $f=0$
2. $\varphi$ is trivial
3. $f=0$ and $\varphi$ is trivial.

Case 1. is the semidirect product, case 3. is the direct product, but what is case 2?

Comment: That is a (possibly)  nonsplit extension with $A$ in the centre.  It is called a *central extension* of $A$ by $G$ (or unfortunately sometimes of $G$ by $A$).

Comment: Oh, really!? Elements of $A$ in the extension are in form $(a,e)$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$, and in case 2, $(a,e)\bullet(a_2,g)=(a+a_2+f(e,g),\,g)$ while $(a_2,g)\bullet (a,e)=(a_2+a+f(g,e),g)$, so if $f(e,g)=f(g,e)$ were true, then elements of $A$ would really commute with every element of the extension. But why is $f(e,g)=f(g,e)$ true?

Comment: Every cocycle is equivalent (via a coboundary) to a normalized cocycle in which $f(e,g) = f(g,e) = 0$ for all $g\in G$. Or, in terms of group extensions, the cocycle $f$ arises from a choice of coset representatives of $A$ in the extension. By choosing the coset representative of the subgroup $A$ to be the identity, we get $f(g,e) = f(e,g)=0$.

Comment: In fact by applying 2 with $g_1=g$, $g_2=g_3=e$, and then again with $g_1=g_2=e$, $g_3=g$, we get $f(g,e)=f(e,g)=f(e,e)$ when $\varphi$ is trivial.

Comment: Really, thank you. Unfortunately, I can't mark this as an accepted answer, although it is actually.

Comment: I note that in the general case (i.e. when $\varphi$ isn't trivial) $f(g,e)=\varphi_g(f(e,g))$, and the identity element of ($A\times G,\,\bullet)$ is $(f(e,g)^{-1},e)$.

Comment: It makes life easier if you work with normalized cocycles!

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just curious about the general case, that's why I've calculated this.

Comment: @DerekHolt I just noticed in your comment that "*unfortunately* sometimes $G$ by $A$". Why do you prefer here $A$ by $G$? The justification of "$G$ by $A$ "is that we usually extend the base by the fiber (see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+extension#Definition)). But what justifies the "$A$ by $G$"?