# General formula for group extensions by an Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-extensions

In an [older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256164/a-special-case-of-group-extensions-other-then-the-semidrect-product) I wrote this:

> It's a well-known fact that if $A$ an Abelian group and $G$ is a
>   group, then all group extension of $G$ by $A$ is isomorphic with the
>   group ($A\times G,\,\bullet)$, where the group operation $\bullet$ is
>
> $$(a_1,g_1)\bullet(a_2,g_2) = (a_1+\varphi_{g_1}(a_2)+f(g_1,g_2),\,g_1g_2)\tag{1}$$
>
> where
>
> 1. $\varphi:(A\times G)\to A: (a,g)\mapsto \varphi_g(a)$ is a group action of $G$ on $A$
> 2. $f: G\times G\to A$ is a cocycle, i.e. satisfies $f(g_1,\,g_2g_3)+\varphi_{g_1}(f(g_2,\,g_3)) = f(g_1g_2,\,g_3)+f(g_1,\,g_2)$.

I've deduced (1) from Shafarevich's Basic Notions of Algebra and from [this Wikpedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Outer_semidirect_products) but I dind't see this formula explicitly written nowhere. Does anybody know an explicit reference for this very formula?

Comment: That formula in in the proof of Thm 7.30 in the Springer edition of Rotman's book on group theory.

Comment: Yes, the formula is this, but the fact that this is the general formula for the group extensions isn't written explicitly.