# Concise notation for the central extension defined by a cocycle

Tags: group-theory, notation, group-actions, group-cohomology, group-extensions

Any extension of a group $G$ by the Abelian group $A$  is determined (up to isomorphism) by $\varphi$ and $f$, where

1. $\varphi:G\times A\to A$ is a group action of $G$ on $A$
2. $f:G\times G\to A $ is a cocycle.

(see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256164/a-special-case-of-group-extensions-other-then-the-semidrect-product))

- The special case when $f=0$ and $\varphi$ is trivial is the *direct
  product* of $A$ and  $G$ and it is denoted by $A\times G$.
- The special case when $f=0$, but $\varphi$ is possible nontrivial is the *semidirect product* of $A$ and $G$ and it is denoted by
  $A\rtimes_\varphi G$
- The special case when $\varphi$ is trivial, but $f$ is an arbitrary cocycle is the *central extension* of $G$ by $A$ and I didn't find a concise notation for it (it should contain $A$, $G$ and $f$). Is there any? (if isn't there any, then what about $A\otimes_f G$ or $A\odot_f G$?)

(and perhaps the general case also deserves some concise notation, containing $A$, $G$, $\varphi$ and $f$)

Comment: ie. $ A\subset Z(H), H= \bigcup_{g\in G}h_gA, h_xh_y = h_{xy}f(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a notation in [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+extension#CentralExtensionClassificationByGroupCohomology) (definition 3.10). According to this notation, the central extension of $G$ by $A$ defined by cocycle $f$ is $$G\times_f A$$

Comment: I've found the same notation in Varadarajan's Geometry of Quantum Theory (on p. 253, in Theorem 7.8). I note that Varadarajan uses the term *extension of A by G* instead of *extension of G by A*. According to nLab, the more conventional terminology is the latter because the extension is always regarded of the base by the fiber.